# How to add a symbol in a middle of a file name in PS

Tags: powershell

I have modified several thousand files with a various things requested by the owners.
Now, I need to add one final thing and I am not 100% on how to do it.

Scenario is as follows - all files have a 10 digit number at the start, I need to add a hyphen after the number.  String is a variable but it is always the same length.
1234567890abcdefgh.xls would be an example

I have used GCI to make changes to symbols and static parts but not sure how to call for insertion in a specific place of a file (after the 10th character of a variable string)

Any ideas would be most welcome!

Comment: `'1234567890abcdefgh.xls'.Insert(10,'-')` or `'1234567890abcdefgh.xls' -replace '(^\d+)', '$1-'`. If you'd show the relevant part of your code we could give a more specific answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`string.Insert()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.insert) to insert a string into another at a specific offset:

```
PS ~> '1234567890abcdefgh.xls'.Insert(10, '-')
1234567890-abcdefgh.xls
```

To apply to all files in a directory, you could do something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -File |Where-Object Name -match '^\d{10}[^-]' |Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Insert(10, '-') }
```

The regular expression pattern `^\d{10}[^-]` will only match file names that start with 10 digits followed by something *other* than a hyphen (to avoid renaming files that already comply with the naming convention)

Comment: Cheers! Marking as an answer as this was the exact requirements. Tested and it worked the charm without affecting other types of files (ones without 10 digits at the start)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `$matches` you get from the capturing groups of a `-match` comparison:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'X:\WhereTheFilesAre' -File) | 
Where-Object { $_.BaseName -match '^(\d{10})([^-].*)' } |
Rename-Item -NewName { '{0}-{1}{2}' -f $matches[1], $matches[2], $_.Extension }
```

or by using the `Substring()` method:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'X:\WhereTheFilesAre' -File) | 
Where-Object { $_.BaseName -match '^\d{10}[^-]' } |
Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Substring(0,10) + '-' + $_.Name.Substring(10) }
```

or use the regex `-replace` operator:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'X:\WhereTheFilesAre' -File) | 
Where-Object { $_.BaseName -match '^\d{10}[^-]' } |
Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '^(\d{10})', '$1-' }
```